# Task Scheduling in Embedded web server with out OS

Tags: operating-system, embedded, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, interrupt

I am doing project on the Embedded web server. The  Embedded server is without the Operating system. At this conditions how the multiple task will be scheduled in such system?

are the  cyclic-executive and super-loop same things?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do interruption technique help to implement multithreading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497542/how-do-interruption-technique-help-to-implement-multithreading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cyclic-executive

with or without interrupts

Comment: Hello mangusta, can you give me idea in both cases ( with and without interrupts). Cheers.

Comment: why don't you browse that? those concepts are quite simple

Comment: can cyclic executive scheduling approach (with or without interrupts) for the simple embedded web server be good choice?

Comment: well, i can't see any other choice if there is no OS

Comment: @ mangusta what about the super-loop scheduling process? are Cyclic executive and super loop approach are same things?